# JPanel Doesn't Update or Repaint until For Loop Finishes

Tags: java, for-loop, jframe, jpanel

I understand that this is probably a very simple problem, but as I've only been working with JPanel and JFrame for one weekend please don't bag on me too much. My issue is that I have this code:

```
package Game_Elements;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Desktop.Action;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.RenderingHints.Key;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game implements KeyListener
{
private JFrame frame = null;
private JPanel panel = null;
int y = 0;
int x = 0;
public boolean W_TRUE;
public boolean S_TRUE;
public boolean A_TRUE;
public boolean D_TRUE;
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{

    if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_W){
            y-= 15;
            panel.setLocation(x, y);
            W_TRUE = true;

    }
    if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_S){
            y+= 15;
            panel.setLocation(x, y);
            S_TRUE = true;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_A){
            x-= 15;
            panel.setLocation(x, y);
            A_TRUE = true;
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_D){
            x+= 15;
            panel.setLocation(x, y);
            D_TRUE = true;
    }
    if(D_TRUE == true  && S_TRUE == true ){
        y+= 15;
        x+= 15;
        panel.setLocation(x, y);
    }
    if(A_TRUE == true  && W_TRUE == true ){
        y-= 15;
        x-= 15;
        panel.setLocation(x, y);
    }
    if(A_TRUE == true  && S_TRUE == true ){
        y+= 15;
        x-= 15;
        panel.setLocation(x, y);
    }
    if(D_TRUE == true && W_TRUE == true ){
        y-= 15;
        x+= 15;
        panel.setLocation(x, y);
    }
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
    if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_W){
        W_TRUE = false;
}
if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_S){
        S_TRUE = false;
}
if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_A){
        A_TRUE = false;
}
if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_D){
        D_TRUE = false;
}
if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
    System.out.println("Running JUMP");
    for(int j = y - 200; j < y; y-= 15){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        panel.setLocation(x, y);
        panel.revalidate();
    }   
    System.out.println("Complete");

}
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

public void frameStart()
{

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setTitle("Desperation");
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)); // otherwise nice exceptions java.awt.AWTError:
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1920, 1050));
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1050));
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    System.out.println("Frame Created");

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    panel.setLocation(1080, 500);
    panel.revalidate();
    frame.add(panel);
    System.out.println("Panel Created");

    frame.addKeyListener(this);
    System.out.println("Listener Created");
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    Game obj = new Game();

    obj.frameStart();
}
```

}

The panel I have, a basic 200x200 blue cube, does not seem to change location until the loop is done running, so it's more of a jump than anything. I understand that the repaint function only runs as soon as possible, and as this is likely the problem, I was wondering if any of you good folks have advice on an alternative method for refreshing it so it doesn't necessarily look smooth, but at least show some progression. Any advice is appreciated as I don't know much at all about JPanel, JFrame, or really JAnything. Thank you!

Comment: Start with [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for what's causing the problem, have a look at [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for a possible solution and [How to use key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to solve what is likely become another question in the future

Answer (score 0):

For refreshing

```
this.revalidate();
```

is a good way to "refresh" your JComponent

Comment: Also `revalidate` effects the layout, assuming the OP is using a layout, but since there's `setLocation` that brings into question that fact

Comment: @MadProgrammer.... Hmmm.... More code needs to be shown, but i see your point.  But, I'm not going to remove the post until there is more code that suggests a different solution. As another problem, would be the thread.sleep continuously running for the given Long time.

Comment: @Darrell Gehring I suggest you switch your Thread.sleep to a Swing Timer  based program. As Thread.sleep is not recommended for the program that you are trying to create.

Comment: @DarkV1 I added more info. This is a test so please have mercy on my poor indentation.